# Select rows with timestamp of difference of 1 Hour or more

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have a table in a database and I want to fetch records from it but with a little complex condition.

Every 30 minutes, three records are added into the table. Now I want to retrieve the records but those with one hour difference. So basically, if 3 records are added at 1 PM and then 3 are added at 1:30 PM and then another 3 at 2PM, I want to be able to fetch the records added at 1PM and 2PM but leave out 1:30PM.

I would give my code but I am using Laravel and I think not everybody would be able to understand Eloquent, the query builder Laravel uses.

P.S:

```
public function hours24()
{
    $data = new Main();
    $temp = $data->order_by('updated_at', 'desc')->first();
    $time = strtotime($data->updated_at);
    $data = $data->where('updated_at', '>=', date('Y-m-d H:i', strtotime('-1 day')))->where('updated_at', '>=', $time + 3600)->get();
}
```

The problem with above is I am adding 3600 seconds everytime to $time which is a fixed time and so it will only work for the first row since after that each row would techincally be more than an hour apart. There seems no way to increase 3600 for each row.

Comment: [function_timestampdiff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff)

Comment: you can add Laravel tag and put your eloquent code so PHP guys and Laravel guys both can understand it.

Comment: [function_timediff](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff)

Comment: Add the code you have

Comment: Add code of eloquent man!!

Comment: I have added the code.

Comment: why don't you just use mysql functions?

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile I'd be more than happy to use them if they can solve the problem? Let me know if you got a solution?

Comment: @HenrySpike see the links I have provided above

Comment: @MasivuyeCokile Hey man, that would only work if I know the timestamps. I want to compare the timestamps of two rows, select if more than an hour, then move on to the next one and compare it with the last one and repeat the same thing over and over again.

Comment: sql is not the best tool for such recursive requests, but you can attract more attention to the question if you prepare an example in http://sqlfiddle.com/ and expected output, so curious minds could play with it and might give you a good advice.

Comment: @HenrySpike Are rows always inserted at the top and the middle of the hour? Or is it sliding (i.e. every 15th and 45th minute)?

Comment: @peterm I think they may be inserted at 15th minute and then 45th minute! But if that is difficult, I am OK with limiting the insertion at the start and middle of the hour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're interested in records that are being inserted in a fixed time window  - around the top of the hour, let's say +/- 5 min you can do something along the lines of

```php
Main::whereRaw('updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY')
    ->where(function ($query) {
        $query->whereRaw('MINUTE(updated_at) > 54')
            ->whereRaw('MINUTE(updated_at) < 6')
    })
    ->get();
```

which translates to the following raw query

```sql
SELECT * 
  FROM main
 WHERE (MINUTE(updated_at) > 54
    OR MINUTE(updated_at) < 6)
   AND updated_at >= NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY
```

Here is [dbfiddle](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.2&fiddle=328be9a8610218c7b4ca13b4975dbde6) demo

Comment: You dont know how much in debt I owe to you for this one. Thanks a ton.

Comment: in debt I am to you*